# How do I enable HTTPS on subdomain hosted on GitHub pages?

Tags: github, https, subdomain, cloudflare

I have a naked domain (`sebsartlist.com`) hosted on one server (`carrd.io`), but want to host a subdomain `pro.sebsartlist.com` on Git hub pages. I have managed to host the subdomain on GitHub pages but can't seems to get it to "Enforce HTTPS".

I use cloudflare for DNS settings and used the `CNAME` method to point pro.sebsartlist.com to username.github.io so wasn't sure I could also add `A name` records as these point to the naked domain currently.

I have tried to force HTTPS using cloudflare.

I did this by using the options in the crypto settings menu but I still cannot enable HTTPS.

I have also checked that the files I am hosting all point to HTTPS URLs in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find answers for this today so i spent a while messign about with it.
And i figured it out.

1. set the CNAME records to all point to your .github.io page link
2. change the custom domains to somethign else and back so it will refresh the certificates.
3. enable https once the certificates have been issued

and its done.